# What replacement for Service Fabric's IReliableStateManager.TryAddStateSerializer<T>?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Using the latest Service Fabric SDK, we would like to replace the restrictive DataContractSerializer with a custom IStateSerializer that uses JSON serialization. We have found the IReliableStateManager.TryAddStateSerializer method, however it is marked as [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.ireliablestatemanager#Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Data_IReliableStateManager_TryAddStateSerializer__1_Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Data_IStateSerializer___0__).

How else can we register a custom IStateSerializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no alternative way. Using it in this way is supported, but the way it works will change somewhere in the future. You should make the call based on whether you're prepared to deal with that uncertainty.